# How to measure internet speed or bandwith

Tags: networking, bandwidth-measuring

in my country the ISP providers sell internet bandwidth plans stating that only 40% is assured; however, as you may have guessed, the real bandwidth varies a lot and I have personally experienced for several hours bandwidth of 1%. I would like to know if there is a programmatic way to measure the internet bandwidth so I can create a report and file a complaint to the ISP provider. This [page](https://www.speedtest.net/es) is used to manually measure the internet speed and it is the reference here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Speedtest CLI to setup automated scripts, to collect connection performance data and view the results in a CSV, JSONL or JSON format.

https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli